# Jenkins Running on Websphere 8.5 causes plugin class load errors

Tags: java, jenkins, websphere, classpath, artifactory

I am running Jenkins (1.552) on `WebSphere 8.5` with `Java 7` on `RedHat Linux.`  I loaded the Artifactory plugin into Jenkins, but when I hit test connection, I receive the following error:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: 

org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Class 

org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger does not implement Log
```

After looking around, it appears that the Artifactory plugin was not compiled with the `pluginFirstClassLoader` option.  It appears due to this that the WebSphere JARs are being loaded first which contain a different version of the `commons-logging JAR`.  I am seeing this as well with some other plugins.

Does anyone know of a way (without recompiling the plugins) to have the plugin JARs loaded before the `WebSphere JARs?`  I do have the classpath for the application in WebSphere set to be Parent Last.

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem? Running into same issue