# Jenkins-Artifactory plugin on WAS 8.5 class load errors

Tags: jenkins-plugins, cloudbees, artifactory

I am running Cloudbees Jenkins (1.554.2.2) on WebSphere 8.5 with Java 7 on RedHat Linux. I loaded the Artifactory plugin into Jenkins, but when I hit test connection, I receive the following error:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: 
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Class 
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger does not implement Log
```

It appears that the WebSphere JARs are being loaded first which contain a different version of the commons-logging JAR. I am seeing this as well with some other plugins.

I do have the classpath for the Jenkins in WebSphere set to be Parent Last. Also, Jenkins.war directory contains the `commons-logging-1.1.3.jar` and `log4j-1.2.9.jar` files.

Has anyone using artifactory plugin on Websphere 8.5 has encountered the issue.

This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22378330/jenkins-running-on-websphere-8-5-causes-plugin-class-load-errors)